# How to find all the rows that share the same value on two columns?

Tags: find, share

Dataset example:

```
          sex   favourite_meal   favourite_color   age   weight(kg)
Tom        M        pizza             red          18       90
Jess       F        lasagna           blue         20       43
Mark       M        pizza             red          30       68
David      M        hamburger         purple       25       70
Lucy       F        sushi             green        18       47
```

How can I compare each row with the others and find which one share for example the same (sex,favourite_meal) couple. The idea is to check on a large dataset which rows share the same values on two attributes (columns). In this example would be Tom and Mark which share (M, pizza); how to do the same on a large dataset where you can't check by eye?

Comment: What have you searched for and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

One `awk` option is process the source data twice.  First get the count of uniq values in columns 2 and 3 into an array. Then use those counts to filter the data:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {p[$2" "$3]++} FNR<NR {for(n in p) if (p[n]>1 && $2" "$3==n) { print}}' m.dat m.dat
Tom        M        pizza             red          18       90
Mark       M        pizza             red          30       68
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas to do this

```
import pandas as pd

# Initialize data to Dicts of series.
d = {'Name': pd.Series(['Tom', 'Jess', 'Mark', 'David', 'Lucy']),
 'sex': pd.Series(['M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F']),
 'favorite_meal': pd.Series(['pizza', 'lasanga', 'pizza', 'hamburger', 'sushi']),
 'favorite_color': pd.Series(['red', 'blue', 'red', 'purple', 'green']),
 'age': pd.Series([18, 20, 30, 20, 18]),
 ' weights(kg)': pd.Series([90, 43, 68, 70, 47])
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


for y, x in df.groupby(['favorite_meal', 'sex']):
    print("....................")
    print(x.to_string(index=0, header=0))
```

In each iteration, the ***for*** loop is operating on a set of similar rows.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. The problem is that in my real dataset when I do this the notebook tells me: IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)

Comment: This blog has the solution to your problem.  [https://www.bytepro.io/blog/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-the-notebook-server-will-temporarily-stop-sending-output/](https://www.bytepro.io/blog/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-the-notebook-server-will-temporarily-stop-sending-output/)